# Repository created on GitHub cannot be used a NetBeans project

Tags: github, netbeans, github-desktop

I have created a repository on GitHub (site/server) and have managed to clone it on my development PC using GitHub Desktop. However, if I try to use the same repository directory in Netbeans IDE (v12.6), I fail to do so because NB only allows to Create a "new [NB] project" or open an "existing [NB] project". But the repository is clearly not an NB project.

I am looking for a solution to make the repository into a NB project as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sangham

Comment: Can you [edit] the question: (a) what version of NetBeans are you using? (b) Is this GitHub repository empty? Or does it already contain Java artifacts (source code, etc.) - and if so, what is the structure? (c) In NetBeans, what specific steps did you follow - and what specific error did you encounter?

Comment: I have not added the NetBeans version